# Does Romans 1:23 forbid depictions of anthropomorphized animals?

Tags: romans

Does Romans 1:23 mean that anthropomorphic animal characters are problematic?

> and exchanged the glory of the immortal God for images of mortal man
> and birds and animals and reptiles.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your contribution.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Answer (score 2):

Anthropomorphic animals are NOT what Rom 1:23 is discussing.  Note what it is saying:

> and exchanged the glory of the immortal God for images of mortal man
> and birds and animals and reptiles.

That is, these wicked people exchange the glory of the invisible God for images of:

- mortal man
- bird
- animals
- reptiles

That is, in accordance with the second commandment, it is against the law to make images of God and then worship them.  See Appendix quoted below.

Thus, making images of anthropomorphic animals is not wrong. [Indeed, Eze 1 contains word pictures of cherubim that are a combination of animals and mankind. The sanctuary also contained similar images of god and embroidery.]  It is making images (of anything) in order to worship them that is wrong!

**APPENDIX - The Second Commandment, Ex 20:4-6**

> **4** You shall not make for yourself an idol in the form of anything in the heavens above, on the earth below, or in the waters beneath.
> **5** You shall not bow down to them or worship them; for I, the LORD your God, am a jealous God, visiting the iniquity of the fathers on
> their children to the third and fourth generations of those who hate
> Me, **6** but showing loving devotion to a thousand generations of
> those who love Me and keep My commandments.

Answer (score 1):

Romans 1:23 does not forbid anything. The full sentence (1:22 - 23, cited from the ESV) says:

> Claiming to be wise, they became fools, and exchanged the glory of the immortal God for images resembling mortal man and birds and animals and creeping things.

This is a description of some foolish people. There is no prescription explicit in the text. There is no implication that creating images of "man and birds and animals and creeping things" is either spiritually harmful or spiritually beneficial.

The people being described are foolish. The example of their foolishness is that they traded the "immortal glory of God" for their arts. That doesn't imply that the arts are either good or bad, but only that they shouldn't have been traded for something of infinite, eternal value.